# Positive Lookbehind does not do what I expected

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

- I want to find all string positions where a non-space is starting after 2 or more spaces
- I want to find also all string positions at start of line after 0 or more spaces.

my code:

```
r=['  200      200      200      200    ', '    3,50     3,50     3,50     3,50 ', ' 1000     1000     1000     1000    ', '1.000    1.000    1.000    1.000    ']

import regex
I=[]
p = regex.compile("^(?<=\s*)\S|(?<=\s{2,})\S")
for n in range(0,len(r)):
    itemp = []
    for m in p.finditer(r[n]):
       itemp.append(m.start())
    i.append(itemp)
```

This regex does not catch the first '1000' in r[2]

I tried this regex too:

```
p = regex.compile("^\S|^(?<=\s+)\S|(?<=\s{2,})\S")
```

but that doesn't catch the first number as well.

What did I wrong?

Comment: @rock321987, lookbehind yes. I changed it.

Comment: "The contained pattern must only match strings of some fixed length, meaning that `abc` or `a|b` are allowed, but `a*` and `a{3,4}` are not ..." (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) **oops**: "References and conditional references to groups with fixed length are now allowed in lookbehind assertions" (https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.5.html#re) (but I'll let it stay up here for the next one to fall for this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the `^` part of the lookbehind so that it was not "consumed":

```
>>> p = regex.compile("(?<=^\s*)\S|(?<=\s{2,})\S") # <= HERE
>>> I=[]
>>> for n in range(0,len(r)):
    itemp = []
    for m in p.finditer(r[n]):
        itemp.append(m.start())
    I.append(itemp)


>>> I
[[2, 11, 20, 29], [4, 13, 22, 31], [1, 10, 19, 28], [0, 9, 18, 27]]
```

When you keep it outside, the start of string zero-width assertion (or just a "caret") anchors the expression and looks for a non-whitespace right at the beginning of the string (and in case of  `1000....` does not match that - thus, a missing part in your initial results).

And here is the regex demo at [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%5cs*)%5cS%7c(%3f%3c%3d%5cs%7b2%2c%7d)%5cS&i=++200++++++200++++++200++++++200++++%0d%0a++++3%2c50+++++3%2c50+++++3%2c50+++++3%2c50+%0d%0a+1000+++++1000+++++1000+++++1000++++%0d%0a1.000++++1.000++++1.000++++1.000+).

Note that you can use `re` module as well with capture groups:

```
r=['  200      200      200      200    ', '    3,50     3,50     3,50     3,50 ', ' 1000     1000     1000     1000    ', '1.000    1.000    1.000    1.000    ']

import re
I = []
p = re.compile(r"^\s*(\S)|\s{2,}(\S)")
for n in range(0,len(r)):
    itemp = []
    for m in p.finditer(r[n]):
        if (m.group(1)):              # Check if Group 1 matched
            itemp.append(m.start(1))  # Then get its start pos
        else:                         # Then Group 2 matched
            itemp.append(m.start(2))  # Get its start pos
    I.append(itemp)
print(I)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/7jL2S8)

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I still don't understand why `^(?<=\s*)\S` doesn't match. It start from the start of the string, checks if there are 0 or more whitespaces and the next non-space is a match. Why doesn't `' 1000'` give a match?

Comment: The lookbehind requires 0+ whitespace before the current location. Where is the current location? `^` sets the location at the beginning of the string. Then the lookbehind looks for spaces before the beginning of the string. => FAIL. The regex engine does not even search for a non-whitespace, as the zero-width assertion fails already. You need to read more about [**Lookarounds**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Wiktor, thanks. Thanks also for the great sites ***regexstorm*** (is it pure python regex compatible?) and ***Ideone***.

Comment: @Reman: RegexStorm is almost not Python regex compatible, it is .NET compatible, and .NET regex supports infinite width lookbehinds and repeated capture groups. Recursion (`(?1)`, `(?&name)`, `(?R)`) and `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs should be tested at regex101.com.

Answer (score 2):

Other than that, *lookbehinds* seems overcomplicated to me. All that is needed is

```
re.findall(r'\s{2,}(\S+)', s)
```

As for finding position:

```
re.search(r'\S', s).start()
```